# MySQL Vertical Horizontal Sum and Vertical Sum At same time

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables which consist a set of data as below and i want to get the result as in the result which will have a calculation in field `balance`:

I am stuck on the `balance` field, how do i get the `balance` running?

**tblIn**

```
in_date    | code    | in_qty  
-----------|---------|---------
2016-04-01 | aaa     | 100
2016-04-03 | aaa     | 200
2016-04-06 | aaa     | 400
```

**tblOut**

```
out_date   | code    | out_qty  
-----------|---------|---------
2016-04-02 | aaa     | 100
2016-04-08 | aaa     | 400
```

**RESULT**

```
date       | code    | in_qty   | out_qty  | balance
-----------|---------|----------|----------|---------
2016-04-01 | aaa     | 100      | 0        | 100
2016-04-02 | aaa     | 0        | 100      | 0
2016-04-03 | aaa     | 200      | 0        | 200
2016-04-06 | aaa     | 400      | 0        | 600
2016-04-08 | aaa     | 0        | 400      | 200
```

**QUERY**

```
 SELECT
    t.date,
    t. CODE,
    t.in_qty,
    t.out_qty
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            date,
            in_qty,
            0 AS out_qty 
    FROM tblIn
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            date,
            0 AS in_qty,
            out_qty
        FROM tblOut
    ) t
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is not too clear, i have update with more specific thing that i want to achieve

Comment: maybe your `out_qty` of `out_date` 2016-04-08 is 400;)

Comment: thanks for the correction

Comment: Please explain the `balance` column. And is it the expected result that you posted?

Comment: the formula for `balance` column on each row is `previous balance (if null then will be zero) + current in - current out`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT 
t.*,
@prevBalance := (t.in_qty - t.out_qty) + IFNULL(@prevBalance,0) AS balance
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        in_date date,
        code,
        in_qty,
        0 AS out_qty
    FROM tblin

    UNION 

    SELECT 
        out_date,
        code,
        0,
        out_qty
    FROM tblout
) t , (SELECT @prevBalance := NULL) var
ORDER BY t.date;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70c53/2/0)

**Note:**

If you initialize `@prevBalance` variable with `zero` then `IFNULL(@prevBalance,0)` is no longer needed.

So if you use this:

`(SELECT @prevBalance := 0) var`

then change the balance column like below:

`@prevBalance := (t.in_qty - t.out_qty) + @prevBalance`

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, let's do it like this;)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblIn` (
  `in_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblOut` (
    `out_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `code` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `out_qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then try this, maybe work;)

```
SELECT TMP.date, TMP.code, TMP.in_qty, TMP.out_qty, @BALANCE:=@BALANCE + TMP.BALANCE AS balance
FROM (
    SELECT out_date as date,
           code,
           0 as in_qty,
           out_qty,
           0-out_qty as balance
    FROM tblOut
    UNION
    SELECT in_date as date,
           code,
           in_qty,
           0 as out_qty,
           in_qty as balance
    FROM tblIn) TMP,
    (SELECT @BALANCE:=0) B
ORDER BY TMP.date
```

Comment: this awesome, thanks for the solution, both solution is great

Answer (score 0):

You would ordinarily Use a full outer join with date as the common factor, but MySQL doesn't allow for full outer joins.

There's a work around at the link below

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Specify the dates in the ON condition.

Comment: the link is only about how joining the table without other function as i am looking for